# What is the current status of JARVIS?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers-age-of-ultron

Up through *Avengers: Age of Ultron* JARVIS was the intelligent computerized interface used by Tony Stark to run his Iron Man suits, as well as much of his facilities. In the movie, however,

> JARVIS is first damaged by Ultron, then later his "protocols" are uploaded into the construct that becomes Vision.

Subsequently, we see Tony activate a new Iron Man interface called FRIDAY.

Does this imply that JARVIS is no longer exists, at least his original form? Was there only one, unique instance of JARVIS in the world, and that is permanently destroyed?

Comment: I would imagine that we have no way of knowing for sure until Iron Man makes another appearance. Surely Tony has a backup of the original JARVIS somewhere?

Comment: @Omegacron I thought it was slightly odd Tony didn't say 'right, let's get last night's backup of JARVIS restored'

Comment: @PhilPursglove: maybe it got deleted along with all the other data that Ultron nixed before he fled to the internet. *This is why you use Backblaze, Tony.*

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Good point, I'd forgotten about that.

Comment: I guess Tony didn't think to branch the JARVIS code base before modifying JARVIS.

Comment: Having The Vision _and_ JARVIS at the same time would be really confusing. Perhaps even insulting to The Vision. I think it makes sense that Tony opted to move on.

Answer (score 8):

Let's get into the details of this.

> To create Vision, Tony didn't just push JARVIS code into an artificial body. Tony also mentions that he "Reconfigured JARVIS' matrix to be compatible with the body". Meaning, He had modified JARVIS.
>  
>  Most important thing to note is, JARVIS was an AI. Vision is an entire consciousness. He realises this. He is *self-aware*. That is why he says he no longer JARVIS. He has become much bigger. He transcends from an AI to a full consciousness, thanks to the power of the Mind Stone.

Taking these two points into account, we can safely say that when Vision said that

> He was no longer JARVIS.

He actually meant the above. It definitely means that he survived, but has just evolved.

> But to accomplish this, Tony has modified JARVIS, meaning we might never see JARVIS running Tony's suits, or Avengers HQ or his quinjets. The prospect of "Friday" is interesting though.

Comment: I am not comparing JARVIS with Vision. I am asking: After the birth of Vision, did JARVIS survive?

Comment: Ok. I focused more on what became of JARVIS rather than exactly answering. I'll edit it.

Comment: not to be nitpicky, but I think we're told explicitly that JARVIS is *not* an AI; Banner makes that point when they start talking, because Ultron *is* an AI and he acts like that's something new and impressive. Tony explains JARVIS as kind of a souped-up Siri.

Comment: @Michael - yes. Exactly.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield I think Tony Stark is using a different definition of AI than the rest of us. As I recall, he says JARVIS is a "natural language U.I.". For most people, the ability to communicate in natural language means that he *is* an AI.

Comment: Apple's Siri and Microsoft's Cortana are both natural language UI, they're just really primitive compared to JARVIS. As far as we know, JARVIS lacks the capacity to decide to *do something* Tony hasn't programmed it to do.

Comment: So JARVIS became Vision?

Comment: @MaryML - Yup... For all intents and purposes, JARVIS *is* Vision... Or rather, Vision is the living(?!) embodiment of JARVIS.

Comment: +1, despite an apparently odd definition of AI leading to the assertion that Jarvis is somehow an AI while also not sentient.

Comment: may be tony have backup of JARVIS and he will start working with JARVIS

Answer (score 5):

#### While Stark did call [JARVIS](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/J.A.R.V.I.S.) a "souped-up SIRI," I don't think he was being honest. JARVIS was a unique artificial intelligence created by, arguably, the smartest man on Earth. I believe he meant it in a comparative manner, looking at JARVIS in relationship to the alien AI software resident within the Mind Gem.

[image]

*Can your SIRI do this? I didn't think so.*

In the scene where he shows JARVIS in comparison with the software within the Mind Gem, he was comparing JARVIS with the "intelligence software," a far more advanced and completely neural-appearing operating system. JARVIS was likely the most sophisticated AI on Marvel Earth before Stark's attempt at the Ultron AI.

- JARVIS had control of the Iron Legion, maintained all of Stark Enterprises private security, maintained his home defense protocols, ran programs and software integrations in Stark's stead and was able to manipulate and control all of Stark's Iron Men armors, and all of this in real time. JARVIS was also able to even in a semi-disrupted state, upload himself to the internet, hide and still defend the world's security systems and nuclear defense systems from a superior, but still learning, AI housed in Ultron.
- I point these out because I believe there would likely not have been a full back up of JARVIS anywhere. He would have been too unique to easily backup. Given that Tony went to a different interface system when the events in Age of Ultron were over, lends credence to the idea that all that was JARVIS was destroyed and then reintegrated inside of the Vision synthezoid's computerized artificial intelligence which was partially a program derived from the Mind Gem, Ultron and the remnants of JARVIS.

> JARVIS assisted Dr. Bruce Banner and Tony Stark in using the Scepter's "A.I." to finish the peacemaking program codenamed the "Ultron Program". The two scientists left JARVIS alone to upload the A.I. to join a party that the Avengers were having. Afterwards, Ultron awakened and quickly realized its situation.

**Here is the bone of contention:**

> Before JARVIS could contact Banner and Stark, Ultron shut him down, effectively "killing" JARVIS. Secretly, JARVIS went into hiding by spreading its own memory around to avoid detection. When the synthetic body arrived, JARVIS was uploaded into it, becoming an entirely new being: Vision.

- Realistically, it makes no sense for there to have been no copies of JARVIS anywhere, given Stark's incredible resources, so our options are:
- **The Ultron AI attacked (and killed/destroyed/decompiled) not just the instance of JARVIS running in the lab, but every instance of JARVIS running anywhere, preventing him from being able to run on any device capable of contacting Stark.  This meant the fragments of JARVIS that ran into the Internet were ALL the JARVIS that was left. JARVIS would effectively be DEAD.**
- Or perhaps he may have also decided that JARVIS, now housed in the Vision, might be uncomfortable with another instance of itself running around. For Stark, the activation of FRIDAY was his way of paying respect to his old friend/interface and honoring his new relationship with the Vision.

Comment: To be fair, he said that JARVIS *started* as a voice-control interface, but then he immediately follows it up by saying that JARVIS has grown since then, until now he "runs more of the company than anyone but Pepper."  Even Tony isn't claiming that JARVIS is *still* just an interface, by the beginning of A2.