# Is J.A.R.V.I.S (from Iron Man) an artificial intelligence system?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, artificial-intelligence

Is J.A.R.V.I.S, Iron Man's electronic assistant, an example of A.I (artificial intelligence)?

Comment: I've removed `Also is J.A.R.V.I.S a quantum computer?` from your post as we require all questioned to contain only one question. That way you can accept the single best answer,  without having to decide between posts that answer the question separately. Feel free to ask a second question though!

Comment: Also I'm confident that Tony mentions in AoU that Jarvis started as a piece of  voice recognition software. [Interesting comment here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87376/what-is-the-current-status-of-jarvis#comment193167_87644)

Comment: I'm a little confused here.  Are you asking for a specific kind of a.i.?  Even finite state machines are generally considered a.i., and Jarvis definitely has enough branching responses and differing responses to similar questions prior to -deciding- to block/screw with ultron on the internet, to be at least more advanced than that.

Comment: Also, not only do most audience see Jarvis as a character and as having a gender, but I'd put money down that several, if talking to Jarvis on the phone would think him human.  I'm pretty sure he'd pass a Turing test.

Comment: In this rather charming [Iron Man 3 draft script](http://gregorymancuso.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Iron-Man-3-movie-script.pdf), JARVIS is described (explicitly) as an A.I. Now obviously this script never made it into production, but that's a big thumbs up as far as I'm concerned....

Comment: And I say again. If Jarvis was just a program, he could have been restored from a backup. He would have been just software with no unique parameters and could have been retrieved from an old backup. As an artificial intelligence, it would have unique properties which would have made it difficult or even impossible to recreate the exact properties he possessed.

Comment: That's partially true, but some algorithms keep certain sets of previously trained settings so as to back out of overtraining or local maxima scenarios.

Comment: I rolled back the latest edit because it's not clear which definition of A.I. Pecoru wants to use.

Comment: @ThaddeusHowze His unique properties had to be stored somewhere, A.I. or not. They could have been deleted.

Comment: Your washing machine has an AI in it. I think what you really is asking is, is it a "strong/general AI".

Answer (score 19):

**No.**

He seems like it, but in *Age of Ultron* when describing how Ultron is an actual AI, Tony Stark proclaims that Jarvis is an incredibly sophisticated program that mimics sentience very well, but does not actually meet the conditions for full AI (i.e. sentience).

The whole point of The Vision being "not Jarvis" even though he sounds like Jarvis and originates from Jarvis's code is that he's been augmented with *actual* AI, giving him consciousness that he did not have before, resulting in a new "being". If Jarvis were already an AI, none of this would make sense.

Mind you, what constitutes "AI" is subject to interpretation.

Comment: If Tony hadn't said it, or you hadn't added that last line, I'd possibly be argumentative about your answer.

Comment: @Cone_of_Silence: So, if I'd written a _different_ answer, you'd have been argumentative about it? Good to know, I guess! ;P

Comment: I'm not going to argue with Tony Stark, but it looks like [Thaddeus Howze did](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87376/what-is-the-current-status-of-jarvis/89167#89167).

Comment: Until the OP clarifies what definition of AI they're looking to match, I'm going to go with the in-universe canonical on-screen comment.

Comment: @Lightness.    Touche.  I didn't ask the question, so my acceptance of the in universe answer is my own problem, but I have a history with AI, and the in universe answer crawls under my skin and wriggles uncomfortably.

Comment: @Cone_of_Silence: As a software developer and on-off researcher in the field, I'm right there with you! But I can't let personal feelings get in the way.

Comment: @Lightness nice!  I'm computer science grad with an undergrad focus on AI and a (failed masters attempt) in it.  These days I'm basically a management info systems guy.

Answer (score -4):

JARVIS is not an AI system of Tony Stark but indeed a revolutionary invention of Howard Stark, the father of Tony Stark. JARVIS is  an updated feature of Arsenal, and artificial robot, which was made by Howard Stark to look after his son, Tony.

Comment: [Please don't shout.](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/41249)